# Bluetooth : Send AT commends to Headset from Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, hfp

I have established connection between Bluetooh HeadSet and Android phone through HFP profile.

Now I want to send AT commands to HeadSet device.

I have used following components while HFP connection.

**IBluetoothHeadset.aidl**

**BroadcastReciever for ACL**

I am not using any `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` socket connection.

and what does following function do ?

```
boolean sendVendorSpecificResultCode(in BluetoothDevice device,
                                     in String command,
                                     in String arg);
```